# Calling a class in another package in manifest?

Tags: android

I have my projected setup like so:

```
com.myApp.app
```

-----contains the main activities files

```
com.myApp.background
```

-----contains a class with a service

My manifest is setup like so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".background.SendLocationtoServer" >
        </service>
```

I keep getting a problem with it not been able to find the service. Which is obvious as its currently calling `com.myApp.app.background` which isn't correct. I want it to call `com.myApp.background`. I've tried setting this explicitly in the service tag, and also changing the overall package to com.myApp which causes loads of errors and a force close. How do I just tell it to look in the package above?

Comment: Please post the exception you are receiving, and if you can the code where you create and start the intent for the service, that would help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the fully qualified package name when creating the `Intent` to start the `Service`, but I think the easier way is to set up an `Intent` filter for the `Service` (in the Manifest) and then just specify that action in your `Intent` that you create from the outside package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified package name in the `<service>` defined in your manifest.  Right now you are registering a server with a name that resolves to com.myApp.app.background.SendLocationtoServer.  Change the name to com.myApp.background.SendLocationtoServer, or whatever the fully qualified name is.